# Page Processor For Custom Content Type in Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have a custom content type in mezzanine and I am writing a page processor to massage some of the data. However per my experimentation and the documentation [here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-processors). The page processor function will get an instance of Page object, how can I get the custom type I created (which inherits from Page).

page_processor.py

```
from .models import DocPage

@processor_for(DocPage)
def gallery_link(request, page):
    print(type(page))
```

prints out:

```
<class 'mezzanine.pages.models.Page'>
```

I want it to get DocPage, since that is my custom type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. I need to use

get_content_model() method of the Page to get the DocType. 
More info [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mezzanine-users/1443kbkt9y/custom-content-type-and-page-processor).